# How to get current category id - OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add to  in header - if statement:

```
<?php if (category = 17) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="category 17 description" />
<?php } ?>

<?php if (category = 18) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="category 18 description" />
<?php } ?>
```

How can i get current category id

Comment: your category ID passed in URL ?

Comment: its always good to use $ before variable in php like $var

Comment: Why do You need such an overkill? Would You edit the header for every category? What OC version are You running? Isn't it much easier and better approach (or maybe the only right approach) to edit the `/catalog/controller/product/category.php` and add something like `$this->document->addMeta($category_info['description']);`???

Comment: @shadyyx agreed. This is not a good idea.

Comment: @shadyyx thank you, i choosed your answer !

Comment: @Bside I added an answer from the comment so that You can accept it! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Put this before the code in your header

```
$category = empty($this->request->get['path']) ? 0 : (int) array_pop(explode('_', $this->request->get['path']));
```

Then use `$category` instead of just `category` as you have in your question

Answer (score 2):

If you only require the category id , it is a url parameter "path".
So, the best way to access category id in the header.tpl will be

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
  if ($_GET['path'] = 17) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="category 17 description" />
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($_GET['path'] = 18) { ?>
 <meta name="description" content="category 18 description" />
<?php } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to get the Category ID from?

Is it in the url?

Then you have to use the global $_GET variable.

if the url is

`example.com/index.php?category=2`

You can get the parameter with

```
$category= $_GET["category"]
```

Comment: Also you always have to use a ' $ ' before a variable in PHP. SO it should be '$category' and not 'category'

Comment: Hi, it was example for the question

Comment: @Maximii77 Are You sure You are talking about OpenCart? OpenCart uses `request` for this, so instead of directly accessing `$_GET` You would use `$this->request->get`...Also there is no `category` parameter in the `GET` but a `path` parameter...Won't give You -1 because of Your low XP...

Answer (score 0):

I guess best approach to do this is to add `meta description` from within the `category` controller, like this way:

```
$this->document->addMeta($category_info['description']);
```

Just edit Your `/catalog/controller/product/category.php` controller file.

Comment: Unless im mistaken, $this->document->addMeta($m) doesnt exist in the default document class. You can use this vQmod to add it http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21542

Comment: I'm not sure right now since the answer is 2 years old already but it is probable that some older version (prior to 1.5.4.0) had this method implemented, otherwise I couldn't use it in my answer ;-)

Comment: I was wondering that too man, i figured that method would have stayed since its extremely useful in our semantic age. Maybe its in 1.4.x branch or something....or...should be in 2.x or something :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $path = $this->request->get['path'];
    $cats = explode('_', $path);
    $cat_id = $cats[count($cats) - 1];
}
echo $cat_id;
```

Source: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2014/07/get-current-category-in-opencart.html