# opencart - get parent category name/id on a sub-category page

Tags: opencart

I have a code block that I want to execute only on sub-categories of a particular category. I wanted to use breadcrumbs for this purpose but the parent category disappears from breadcrumbs if a SEO url is set for the current sub-category.

Is there a way to get the name or id of the parent category inside a sub-category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every category has a `parent_id` assigned to it. You need to get the `parent_id` based off the current category.

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category` WHERE `category_id` = '123'");
$parent_id = $result->row['parent_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the trick. Though in this case since we are getting the parent_id based upon the current category_id' we need to know how to get the current category id which I found here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14686559/2246217). `$cur_category = empty($this->request->get['path']) ? 0 : (int) array_pop(explode('_', $this->request->get['path']));` and to use it `WHERE `category_id` = '$cur_category'` Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Without sql query

```
$categories = explode('_', $this->request->get['path']);
```