# opencart - get parent category name/id on a sub-category page? New

Tags: php, opencart

Okay, I've been asked to repost this as a moderator deemed it to be a 'new' question to this thread: [opencart - get parent category name/id on a sub-category page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193027/opencart-get-parent-category-name-id-on-a-sub-category-page/21476303#21476303)

I believe it to be a valid question related to that title so have posted it here in compliance. Any help would be very much appreciated:

Being a newbie to this concept I'm struggling to interpret the logic within the original thread [above] when applying it to my particular scenario; I'm trying to display the currently displayed category's parent category name. In category.php I've included the line `$categories = explode('_', $this->request->get['path']);` but am having difficulty in displaying the parent category name. I'm unclear as to the correct variable name to use in category.tpl to display this. Could someone please advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find (catalog/controller/product/category.php) around line 95

```
if ($category_info) {
```

Add inside

```
if($category_info['parent_id'] != 0){
 $this->data['parent_cat_info'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_info['parent_id']);
 }
```

now in template file (/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl) you can access the properties of array  `$parent_cat_info` 
e.g for category name echo `$parent_cat_info['name']`

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, Ramesh - this works in sub-categories but when in a top (base) category I get the error 'undefined variable parent_cat_info'. Is there a way to conditionally eliminate the variable if in a top category? Thanks.

Comment: As u already said for the top(root) category there is no parent category so default parent is 0, That's why it is showing error message,

In template file first check if value exists

<?php if(isset($parent_cat_info)){
  echo $parent_cat_info['name'];
} ?>

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks for taking the time to explain. I had searched high & low for this for quite some time. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> In page catalog/controller/product/catalog.php
>
> find the line

```
if ($category_info) {
```

> Then add below code inside above line

```
$data['parent_cat_info'] = array();
            if($category_info['parent_id'] != 0){
                $data['parent_cat_info'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_info['parent_id']);
             }
```

> and in page catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/product/category.tpl
>
> add where you like to diaplay

```
<?php //print_r($parent_cat_info);
  if($parent_cat_info){
    echo $parent_id=$parent_cat_info['category_id'];
    echo $parent_name=$parent_cat_info['name'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way easier way to get them.

If you install the export/import tool that exports the DB into an xls.

It has the cateogory id and name associated on the category tab inside the xls.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17

Its very simple and elegant, best method is to simply not convolute. :)

Hope this helps everyone.

Cheers

NickTailor
nicktailor.com

Comment: Ramesh's solution worked as the requests need to be dynamic, not hard coded. I've been using export/import for quite a few years already but thanks for the thought.